# Detect if facebook user is logged in with no popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to check if the user is logged in in facebook (and redirect to other page) but I can't open any popup for this:

This will work: but would open a popup in case the user is NOT logged in facebook

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if(response.status == 'connected')
              /*Redirect here*/
});
```

This is working in another web of mine, but not here

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : myAppid, // App ID 
                  status     : true, // check login status
                  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
                      /* REDIRECT HERE */
                });
              };
              // Load the SDK Asynchronously
              (function(d){
                 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js";
                 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
               }(document));
```

Any clue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to get the info you want.

> The first time in the current browser session that `FB.getLoginStatus` is called, or the JS SDK is init'd with `status: true`, the response object will be cached by the SDK. Subsequent calls to `FB.getLoginStatus` will return data from this cached response.

Example from documentation:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
});
```