# How to check if a user is logged in to facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am totally new to facebook api and I wanted to ask , whats the easiest and fastest way to know if a person is logged in to facebook.

One solution that I tought of is to send a javascript or php request and see if i get some status code that tells me whether the person is logged in or not (say if it returns 404, then that means he isnt logged in).

update:

I found this easy "hack":

```
    function logged() {
    alert('logged');
}
function notlogged() {
    alert('not logged');
}
</script>

<script src="http://www.facebook.com/ajax/composer/attachment/question/question.php" onload="logged()" onerror="notlogged()">
```

But it doesnt work... however, thats the type of code that i am looking for..code that would send a request and if fails, it will throw an error

```
**update**
```

I dont want to trigger any suspicion from the user that I am checking if he is logged in. So if there is a use of app_id, then I would think that I need the users permission to use my app..that is a burden cause I will have to take another authentication step.

**I cant have the user know that he is being authenticated in any way regarding facebook**

Comment: Which part of the API are you using and where? In an application, on your website, authentication?

Comment: I am not using any api, and I know little about facebook api.. but I know there are indirect ways of checking whether a user is logged in or not..see my update

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your code correctly, only if no session is returned do you do the redirect? According to comments in Facebook's example: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php (great place to this info huh?), even if you get a session back, you can't assume it's still valid. Only trying an API call that requires a logged in user will you know for sure. This is the best way I've seen to  reliably determine login/logout status.

```
if ($session) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    if ($me) {
      //User is logged in
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //User is not logged in
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. so it is a facebook api.. can you give me about where you there are more details on that api?

Comment: check my latest update however.. I am about wary of using app_id cause it might trigger another authentication

Answer (score 1):

try This, Hope this will help

```
include 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => $app_id, // your application id
 'secret' => $app_secret, // your application secret
'cookie' => false,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();


$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' =>  '// put your permission'
        )
);

if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$permissions = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');   
   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
 }  

 if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
  }
```

Comment: isnt there is a problem with using app_id, because the user must give his consent to use my app...and it will trigger authentication anyway?!?

Comment: To use php api then you need application i mean app_id its mendatory. By the way where you want to check the facebook login status?In your website? if yes then you need a application for app_id, app_secret to use php api.

Comment: but wont the user have to authenticate to use my application? so it requires another authentication step? doesnt it? if it does, I will have to use another hack

Comment: So I am screwed. .. cause I cant have the user see that I am checking that he is logged or logged out out of facebook

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939712/is-it-possibile-to-check-within-php-if-a-user-is-logged-in-facebook . but you need application must. so create application use that app id and secret . using api you can check facebook session from above link. so when you get session value then do your stuff when dont get just do nothing i mean no redirect for login.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a facebook "tab" then limited user information is provided to you as part of the signed_request. And for a facebook tab, you need to create an app.

Otherwise, without an App ID and alerting the user YOU CANNOT DO IT.

There have been hacks in the past, some of the cleverer ones have been to put up comment boxes and measure the hieght of the containing DIV (they used to be larger if logged in) or to include the facebooks FBML tabs to show a log in button (log in was wider) but theses were all stamped out as they were discovered. The same probably goes for the link you tried in your question.

Facebook, for all the debate on rpivacy, won't knowlingly leak information - until you get an app id, ask the user then you can get nearly everything...

Comment: I found a hack that does work, Robbie,,so you are wrong , mate

Comment: Well good luck seeing it still work in a few weeks. Been through this cycle a few times already ;)

Comment: Wow, from knowing nothing about the API to l33t h4x0r in an hour – Dmitry is The Man, mad respects Yo!

Comment: @MatthewRay - Thanks. The solution you linked is basic Facebook stuff, and uses an APP ID and the only way of knowing if the user is logged in or not will show a prompt. This question is asking for doing it without an APP ID / prompt. Did you paste the wrong link?

Comment: @Robbie That is the correct link, only you are not offering a prompt to the user. You are simply requesting the SDK and if your response is "not_authorized" then you know that they ARE logged into facebook but you have not prompted them for facebook's OAuth authentication. If it is anything else, they are not logged into facebook.

Comment: Sorry - you're missing an earlier edit / discussion of this question. The user wanted to do it without an App ID or without letting the user know in anyway they were being checked against Facebook. The link you show needs an AppID and also triggers the FB.init functionality etc - so it doesn't answer what the original question was.

Answer (score -1):

Check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10698594/1789650

This should answer your question. You have to load the javascript SDK to get it to work correctly.

Comment: The linked answer won't show you if the user is logged in if they have not authorized your app. You still need to get them to authorize your app before you know if they are logged in or not.