# Create a php page to detect if a user is logged into Facebook or not

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to know if this is possible, and ideally some links to tutorials/code etc. That would be ideal!

So I would have a page called "detect.php". A user visits this page and if they are logged into Facebook they are taken to one URL, if they aren't they go to another

So this needs to work even if they don't currently have Facebook open in the same Browser, so I guess it is Cookie related?

I have spoken to a programmer about it, and they are saying its not possible unless you first create an app and allow Facebook permissions for that user. Doesn't make sense to me

If there is no official Facebook way, perhaps a workaround or other ideas?

Thanks alot

Comment: The programmer was right, you do need to create a facebook. Try reading the facebook docs to understand the app flow https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: _“Doesn't make sense to me”_ – well, you might have heard of a thing called _privacy_ …? It is of course none of your beeswax whether or not I am currently logged in to Facebook, as long as I decide to explicitly tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The programmer was right, you need to create a facebook app in order to detect if user is logged in facebook, however creating a facebook app is fairly easy and code for user status should look like this: `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    //redirect here
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
    //redirect here
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
});`[Detect if facebook user is logged in with no popups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698475/detect-if-facebook-user-is-logged-in-with-no-popups/10698594#10698594)